# Teams/Theme.css gives a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, 404-not-found

When opening my inbox on on MSE, MSO, SU or SO I see a 404 resource not found for:

`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/teams/theme.css?v=10056:1520526728:10063:1520539764`

Notice the /teams/ there. I'm part of the teams beta on Stack Overflow but this issues hunts me on every site.

Due to this error my Inbox notification keeps popping up, indicating I have unread messages, which is not the case because I've already read all of them.

[image]

Can this be looked at?

Comment: We're investigating!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a bunch of security checks in play here that effectively switch off access to the secured backend where teams reside if the top-level site doesn’t support them.

When requesting inbox messages we send your request to the teams backend if you are in a team anywhere on the network so we can render your teams messages securely (the regular sites don’t have any access to those databases). In this case we forgot to add an exception so that inbox messages can be rendered from any SE site.

That fix has been built out to production so you should be all set! Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: "if you are in a team anywhere on the network"...so teams exist on other network sites as well?

Comment: Well, they *could*... There’s nothing in particular tying it to SO...