# Inbox "View all inbox items" button seems to have vanished

Tags: support, status-completed, global-inbox

(Possibly [Teams-related](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56962319#56962319))

At the top of my inbox, there used to be a "View all inbox items" button.  But it appears to have just vanished:

[image]

It's not [just me either](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8747767#8747767), but it seems to be appearing [for some](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8747813#8747813) and not others.  Or [it's been gone for a while](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8747839#8747839) and I never noticed.  If it's a bug... can we fix it?

Comment: Just to add a data point, I still have it. I didn't dv by the way.

Comment: I have it at both the top and the bottom of my inbox list

Comment: Oh I just noticed you were talking about the link at the bottom. I have one at the bottom but another link that says "all items" at the top. Based on your screenshot you don't have either.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Can I see a screenshot please?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfZ8a.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljIdL.png here is one with both

Comment: Btw, until this gets fixed, you can get to that page using this link: https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox

Comment: i see it both at the top, and the bottom when i scroll through all the entries that are there. No userscripts for the menu,  disabled the sticky header, no teams,

Comment: I have a bunch of userscripts but I don't see it any more regardless of whether the scripts are on or off.

Comment: Teams users? @Ollie are you on any teams?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Yep, I'm on a team.  Hopefully it's not for Teams-users only.

Comment: @Luuklag are you on a Team?

Comment: Wouldn't it be kindof weird if it was a teams issue that affects all sites? I thought teams only showed up on SO

Comment: @user400654 wouldn't be the first time something from teams messes up the inbox: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309049/369802. Luuklag confirmed in chat he's not on any teams, aibobot isn't either... So it's the most likely bet :) [Catija said she'd try to ask around](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8748115#8748115)

Comment: A good set of search terms to attempt to find any related bugs across all the sites is: [`"all inbox items [support] or [bug]"`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=all+inbox+items+%5bsupport%5d+or+%5bbug%5d&pagesize=50).

Comment: The inbox button didn't disappear for me, must have been a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

As several users observed, this issue only impacted Teams users.  When a user is a member of a Team, the inbox in the topbar served both network and team inbox items, but the page linked to in "all items" page didn't. This could be confusing for users who had only ever participated on a Team, as clicking the link would take them from a full inbox to an empty page.

A stopgap was to hide the "all items" link from Teams users until they had a full inbox with 100 items in it. The idea was that this would give the team time to build an inbox view on Stack Overflow and let seasoned network users be "grandfathered" into seeing the link in the meantime.

Unfortunately, seasoned users won't always have exactly 100 items, due to the way we collapse related inbox items. I personally have been at 94 since I started looking at this bug.

The good news is that Teams has in fact implemented their own inbox views by way of the "For you" page and moved all but one team off of the global inbox, so I just pulled out the offending line and we'll show the link to everyone again.

Comment: How come you have double space after each period? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Cause.Doesn't it look better like that? ;)

Comment: @Ollie nah, looks like some IDE or smartphone keyboard in action.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating It's largely because that's how I was raised, but I've got arguments to defend it.  First and foremost, I do a lot of writing on fixed width editors and the science continues to support the idea that two spaces help with readability in that context.  The second reason is that even if I do, I isn't hurting anyone, so why change?  HTML collapses extra spaces between words so I can have a post with high readability in both Markdown/code view and rendered HTML.

Comment: @Brian huh, interesting, and now that you say it, think you already told me before, long ago, when you were the iOS Super Developer... :-)

Comment: All this has happened before, and all this will happen again.